# Flex Release build Security Sandbox Violation Error #2048

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework, zend-amf

I'm developing a web application with Flex and PHP using the ZendAMF protocol. Since yesterday I have this strange problem occurring whenever I'm publishing the application to the remote server.
Locally everything works fine it's only when I publish it on the server. Here is the ErrorMessage I get:

```
Send failed
Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://mydomain.com/login/MainFrame.swf cannot load data from http://localhost/bin-debug/gateway.php. url: 'http://localhost/bin-debug/gateway.php'
```

I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my gateway.php and amf_config file since I know that they are slightly different. (I'm using these files from a backup place where things did work)

Further on I copied my crossdomain.xml also on the web root and on the application dir where it automatically get into. This is the content:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The problem is that in production release it's still trying to access the local files. I've tried searching a lot about this problem but didn't found the same as my case.

gateway.php source part

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$webroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$configfile = "$dir/amf_config.ini";

//default zend install directory
$zenddir = $webroot. '/ZendFramework/library';

//Load ini file and locate zend directory
if(file_exists($configfile)) {
    $arr=parse_ini_file($configfile,true);
    if(isset($arr['zend']['webroot'])){
        $webroot = $arr['zend']['webroot'];
        $zenddir = $webroot. '/ZendFramework/library';
    }
    if(isset($arr['zend']['zend_path'])){
        $zenddir = $arr['zend']['zend_path'];
    }
}
```

What can I try next to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you understand what the error is--the remote server is trying to access localhost; which probably won't work.  Are you hard coding a localhost reference somewhere in your code?  Or is it in a config file?  I don't think we can help more without a code review.

Comment: No there is no where a harcoded url used in the application beside in the project settings -> Flex Server where my webroot is set to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs and Root URL to http://localhost/

Comment: I'm not sure what the Flex Server settings from Flash Builder do.  I would not expect it to change your code, though.  Are you compiling a services-config into your main file?  Many AMF implementations use an external config file approach.  I'd look there for a hard-coded 'localhost' reference.  You may also look at any external libraries that you reference.

Comment: @Reboog711 The only config file is the amf_config_ini

Which has following information:

webroot=/home/xx/yyy.com/html
zend_path=/home/xx/yyy.com/html/ZendFramework/library

[zendamf]
amf.production = true
amf.directories[]=services/facade
amf.directories[]=services
amf.directories[]=/home/xx/yyy.com/html/services

Comment: Where do you specify your AMF Endpoint?  What is the code that calls the RemoteObject?

Comment: In the gateway.php file which is auto generated from flex. It doesn't have any configurations in it, it's retrieving them from the amf_config.ini file

Comment: I'll try to ask in a different way.  Please share the Flex Code behind your RemoteObject calls so that I an see how you specify the RemoteObject's destination and endpoint.  The code you shared is server side code, but everything you've shared points to an error in the Flex code.

Answer (score -1):

`http://mydomain.com/` requires information from `http://localhost/`

in this case your `http://localhost/crossdomain.xml` should allow requests from `http://mydomain.com/`

just make sure your crossdomain.xml is ok

Comment: As i said I have no problems what so ever when running the application locally from `http://localhost`. After deployment it is still pointing to localhost where it has to point just to the webserver (`http://mydomain`)

Comment: just look at error message which you posted, the problem is described there, you have 2 domains, now you are telling that you don't have troublems, but your domain (according to error) is trying to get information from localhost - this seems to be wrong

Comment: I have to -1 this.  "localhost" is a special domain that points back to the local server. Unless every single client of an application has their own server running; using localhost in a production app is not practical.  Besides, you're just rehashing the same conversation that @dotNes and I have been having in the comments.

Comment: do what you consider is correct, anyway - the error message is telling the truth, and the truth is that first domain is connecting to second domain, and there is a missing crossdomain.xml file

Comment: @Rodislav while the error is a cross domain issue, that you would normally fix as stated in your answer. However, the real problem is that his SWF is trying to find the PHP server at the end point "localhost". Since the SWF has been deployed to the server, it shouldn't be using "localhost" URL's to access the server. When the SWF and server urls are the same, there will be no cross domain issue -- so fixing it w/a crossdomain.xml is pointless ;)

Comment: well how I see you know that his app have hardcoded url's, they are not in xml, json or sent as parameters, in any case - the problem persist with url's, and all problems related to urls are related to crossdomain.xml